# Using Django-Q in production

Tags: python, django, orm, django-views, cron

I was wondering whether I had to do anything special when using Django Q (https://django-q.readthedocs.io/en/latest/) in production.

I have a Q_Cluster setup and I can run mange.py qcluster to start all my scheduled tasks. Would I be doing the same in production?

Comment: I would think so, unless it is explicitly stated otherwise.

Comment: How would you run the manage.py command in production?

Comment: @TD1 You could use a cron job if you're deploying with a linux server. I used heroku for that project and there was a scheduler extension.

Comment: Thanks @JustinShakergayen. I ended up daemonizing the process using systemd on linux.

Comment: @TD1 Glad to hear you figured it out

Answer (score 7):

Systemd is a good way to manage it. You can also put the logs in a folder attached to the site. I put all my config files in the same folder as the django app, so I can keep them on the same version control. In practice it looks something like this:

/web/example/config/example-qcluster.service:

```
[Unit]
Description=example qcluster daemon
After=network.target

[Service]
User=<web user>
Group=www-data
RuntimeDirectory=example
RuntimeDirectoryMode=0755
PIDFile=/run/example/qcluster.pid
WorkingDirectory=/web/example
EnvironmentFile=/web/example/.env
ExecStart=/web/example/env/bin/python manage.py qcluster
ExecReload=/bin/kill -s HUP $MAINPID
ExecStop=/bin/kill -s TERM $MAINPID
PrivateTmp=true
StandardOutput=file:/web/example/logs/qcluster.std.log
StandardError=file:/web/example/logs/qcluster.err.log

[Install]
WantedBy=multi-user.target
```

Then of course link, enable and start it:

```
sudo ln -s /web/example/config/example-qcluster.service /etc/systemd/system/example-qcluster.service
sudo systemctl enable example-qcluster.service
sudo systemctl start example-qcluster.service
```

Then, you can check it's working by tailing the log:

```
tail -f /web/example/logs/qcluster.std.log
```

Comment: Any suggestions how to do this in a Windows environment? 

https://stackoverflow.com/q/77112904/13791079