# Run Django-Q along with Django's management command runserver

Tags: django, queue, task-queue, django-q

I'm using Django-Q to run some background tasks and schedules. Currently facing two problems here:

1. When stopping the django-q cluster using `CTRL+C` the cluster is not getting stopped properly. Not sure if this is an OS specific issue. I'm using Windows
2. Even when the django server is stopped, since the django-q cluster is running, the configured schedules are also running.

So I'd like for a way to start and stop the django-q cluster along with the django server itself

I was looking for a way to start the django-q cluster to start along with the django server by modifying the `manage.py` file but not sure if it is advisable. and not sure what's the correct way to do it